# Adding a field in parent view

Tags: odoo

i am having some problems when i try to add a field in the parent view.
The class is:

```
class VademecumFraccionamiento(models.Model):
    _name = 'farmacia.vademecum_fraccionamiento'

    _inherits={
        'farmacia.vademecum': 'vademecum_id'
    }

    hijo = fields.Many2one('farmacia.vademecum_fraccionamiento', string="Artículo hijo", index=True)
    vademecum_id = fields.Many2one('farmacia.vademecum', string='Artículo Padre', required=True, ondelete='cascade', index=True)
```

The xml is:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="farmacia_vademecum_fraccionamiento_form_view">
            <field name="name">farmacia_vademecum_fraccionamiento.form</field>
            <field name="model">farmacia.vademecum</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="farmacia_vademecum.farmacia_vademecum_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//page[@string='lalala']" position="after">
                    <page string="Fracc">
                    </page>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//page[@string='Fracc']" position="inside">
                    <group>
                        <field name="vademecum_id">
                        </field>
                     </group>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

The error is:
Error details:
The field `vademecum_id` not exists

I don't know how to solve that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all verify that you have added this py file into to the __init__.py and  restart the server then check.

Comment: Thanks Empiro Technologies, i already added this py file in the __init__.py  but the problem continues

Comment: You made one mistake here you are trying to add that field into the parent view, I guess because you have specified model = farmacia.vademecum name.
According to rule you can specify this field into the farmacia.vademecum_fraccionamiento model not to farmacia.vademecum model.

Comment: You can refer product.product for help in which you can see the product_tmpl_id definition.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Now the error disappeared, but the view is not showing the 'Fracc' page. It is another topic, i have a inheritance between farmacia.vademecum_fraccionamiento -> farmacia.vademecum -> product.product... and if i add a menu for the farmacia.vademecum_fraccionamiento view, it show a lot of fields, almost all from product.product, but i want to see the fields from farmacia.vademecum_fraccionamiento and farmacia.vademecum only. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer addons/product/product_view.xml for more help, in which you will get all the answers of your questions related to inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code to:

```
_columns = {
    'hijo' : fields.Many2one('farmacia.vademecum_fraccionamiento', string="Artículo hijo", index=True),
    'vademecum_id' : fields.Many2one('farmacia.vademecum', string='Artículo Padre', required=True, ondelete='cascade', index=True),
        }
```

This will add the fields to your model

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts in odoo for field inheritance.

**_inherit** : can be used in case you want to extend existing model.

**Example**: adding birth date field in res.partner model

```
class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    birth_date = fields.Date('Birthdate')
```

**_inherits** : can be used in case you want to adept module field in current model.

**Example**: Using customer fields in student model,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    _name = 'stundent.student'

    _inherits = {'res.partner': partner_id}

    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Partner')
```

after adding a `partner_id` field in your model you can use all the fields of partner in xml view of student form & tree.

Hope this helps.